# Which Property should I use when Sending Additional information in a RequestSecurityToken (RST)

Tags: wif, saml, sts-securitytokenservice, geneva-framework

There are a couple of properties that seem to allow this:

Properties (which is a Dictionaty)
AdditionalContext
and Context...

I cannot find any guidelines as to which would be most appropriate to use...

I basically need the requestor of the token to provide me with a "External User Id" and the STS I am building will include that as a claim in the response (RSTR).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the .Claims property - this passes in the requested claims.

Add the "external user id" claim here to indicate to the STS that you need this claim in the RSTR.

Comment: I have used the .Claims property to pass the claim to the STS. So like this: rst.Claims.Add(new RequestClaim("http://somenamespace/externalUserId", false, "123456"); The 'funny' bit is that I get ID3257 - WsTrustSerializationExeption when I do that. I have to change the Dialect (on the Claims property) to be "_http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706/authclaims_". That is most annoying, but it works. Reflecting through the WSTrustSerializationHelper class, it assumes the dialect is "_http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity_" then spits the dummy because it isn't the other.

Comment: That's stupid indeed. Have you set the WSTrust version to 1.3 on the WSTrustChannelFactory? (not sure if that fixes it though)

Answer (score 0):

You must have noticed that manipulating `RequestSecurityToken.Properties` requires custom `WSTrust13ResponseSerializer` and `WSTrust13RequestSerializer` classes to be implemented.

Afterwards you should assign these custom classes to `SecurityTokenServiceConfiguration` class.